# Styles not loading in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a simple html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Firefox title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="static/music/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/">Viberr</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<h3>Here are all my albums:</h3>
<ul>

    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/1">Master of puppets - Metallica</a></li>

    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/2">Black album - Metallica</a></li>

</ul>


</body></html>
```

The problem is that firefox doesn't load css styles. It works well in chrome. I tried to run this page on two different pcs with same result.
Why firefox doesn't load styles?

You can check out the page [here](http://explainphoto.net16.net/firefox/music.html)

Comment: try `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/music/style.css">`

Comment: It's `type="text/css"` not `type="test/css"` in the `link` tag as mentioned by @freestock.tk. Also, this attribute is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There had been a few issues:
1) typo here text no text:
   instead of :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

it should:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

2. Another typo:

use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/music/style.css">
```

IMPORTANT `type="text/css"` is deprecated so you don't need it.

3. This is not correct either:

I hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Take away the type attribute from both links, and it should now work.

Comment: awww, such a dumb typo. Thx

Comment: Please select this as the answer if it answers your question!